# Can any of Ruby's HTML Parsers do JavaScript to see the resulting DOM?

Tags: javascript, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri, hpricot

When trying Hpricot and Nokogiri, the HTML can be fetched and parsed, but can they also execute the Javascript as well so that the content shows on the page?  (shows up in the the DOM).  That's because some page won't show the info unless the JavaScript initialization code has run.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.  You might want to look into using something like [Watir](http://watir.com/) and use a real browser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [envjs](http://github.com/smparkes/env-js) and [johnson](http://github.com/jbarnette/johnson) gems.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Capybara](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). I haven't used it myself but I read about it the other day and it seems like it can execute javascript without using a browser.